# Iterating Hashsets

Tags: java, hashset

Good morning guys

I have a hashset which has different objects

Object has attributes

GroupName 
MachineName
EmailAddress

Now from the HashSet I have to find the Object which has same MachineName and EmailAddress but different Group and add into an arraylist.

thanks

Comment: You have better chances of getting an answer if you (a) tag the question properly, i.e. adding the correct language tag and (b) accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: How about showing some code where you insert the things to your hashset.

Answer (score 0):

A big assumption is that you are using Java:

```
Set<YourObject> yourHashSet = // 
List<YourObject> result = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
for( YourObject o: yourHashSet ){
    if( o.getMachineName().equals("machine1") && o.getEmailAddress().equals("one@example.com")){
        result.add(o);
    }
}

// result will contain a list of matching objects.
```

It's pretty much the same code in any language, but if you are in C# you can use LINQ-Objects to do the something in a nice single statement.

Comment: You solution is perfect but I have bit different requirement         I will give you an example                                            Lets say my Hashset has following values                              
Hewitt , AP1 , test@yahoo.com
Domino , AP1 , test@yahoo.com
Test , AP1 , meta@yahjoo.com
Focus , AP1 , beta@yahoo.com
Now from this Hashset I have to find which of the record has same email and machine name but different group which in above case It is (test@yahoo.com) since it has same machine name but different group .So In the end in final Arraylist I will these two record..

Comment: I really can't work out what you are asking... feel free to ask another question